# tree command in a shell script doesn't append slashes for directories

Tags: bash, shell, tree

I have a shell script executes `tree` command

```
$ cat _tree.sh 
#!/bin/sh
tree -L 2 --charset ascii -I "_tree.sh|LICENSE|README.md|node_modules|nbproject"
$ sh _tree.sh 
.
|-- bower.json
|-- dpl
|-- dst
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
`-- src
    |-- fonts
    |-- images
    |-- scripts
    `-- styles

7 directories, 3 files
$
```

When I execute the command directly,

```
$ tree -L 2 --charset ascii -I "_tree.sh|LICENSE|README.md|node_modules|nbproject"
.
|-- bower.json
|-- dpl/
|-- dst/
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
`-- src/
    |-- fonts/
    |-- images/
    |-- scripts/
    `-- styles/

7 directories, 3 files
$
```

The forwarding slashes(`/`) are appended. How can I make the `_tree.sh` file do this?

Comment: Do you perhaps have tree aliased to `tree -F` in your interactive shell?

Comment: @steeldriver Jesus Christ, How could you know that? I checked my `~/.profile` and found exactly the same alias!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To append trailing slashes for directories, simply revise your code to include the `-F` option, in `_tree.sh`:

```
tree -F -L 2 --charset ascii -I "_tree.sh|LICENSE|README.md|node_modules|nbproject"
```

### Explanation

The `tree` program (for example version 1.7.0) does not append trailing slashes by default. As @steeldriver points out, it may only be due to `-F` option enabled somewhere on your system, such as within `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` defined as an alias, that makes it so you see trailing slashes when you run `tree` on the terminal. To have trailing slashes in your scripts too, simply add `-F` option to your `tree` command.